# Nvidia-Docker API for Python?

Tags: python, docker, nvidia-docker

I am currently running a lot of similar Docker containers which are created and run by a Python script via the official API. Since Docker natively doesn't support GPU mapping, I tested Nvidia-Docker, which fulfills my requirements, but I'm not sure how to integrate it seamlessly in my script.

I tried to find the proper API calls for Nvidia-Docker using Google and the docs, but I didn't manage to find anything useful.

My current code looks something like this:

```
# assemble a new container using the params obtained earlier
container_id = client.create_container(img_id, command=commands, stdin_open=True, tty=True, volumes=[folder], host_config=client.create_host_config(binds=[mountpoint,]),detach=False) 
# run it 
client.start(container_id)
```

The documentation for the API can be found [here.](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

From [Nvidia-Dockers Github](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/Advanced-topics#default-runtime) page:

> The default runtime used by the Docker® Engine is
>   runc, our runtime can become the default one by configuring the docker
>   daemon with --default-runtime=nvidia. Doing so will remove the need to
>   add the --runtime=nvidia argument to docker run. It is also the only
>   way to have GPU access during docker build.

Basically, I want to add the --runtime=nvidia-docker argument to my create_container call, but there is no support for that as it seems.

But since I need to switch between runtimes multiple times during the script execution (mixing Nvidia-Docker and native Docker containers) the quick and dirty way would be to run a bash command using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) but I feel like there has to be a better way.

TL;DR: I am looking for a way to run Nvidia-Docker containers from a Python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`run()` and `create()` methods have `runtime` parameter according to https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html

Which has sense because `docker` cli tool is pretty simple and every command translate in a call to the docker engine service REST API